# Finding perpendicular eigenvectors (secondary school level)

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm working through a set of exercises on finding eigenvectors and eigenvalues of square matrices and have come to this question:

> (i) Show that $\mathbf r = \left( \begin{matrix} -2 \\ 0 \\ 1
> \end{matrix} \right) $ is an eigenvector of $\mathbf A = \left(
>  \begin{matrix} 7 & 4 & -4 \\ 4 & 1 & 8 \\ -4 & 8 & 1 \end{matrix}
>  \right)$ and determine the corresponding eigenvalue.
>
> (ii) State two other eigenvectors of $\mathbf A$ that, together with
>   $\mathbf r$, give three mutually perpendicular eigenvectors and state
>   the corresponding eigenvalues.
>
> (iii) What is the value of $\det \mathbf A$?

Part (i) is not a problem (the eigenvalue works out to be $9$), but I get the impression that the question is set up so that Part (i) naturally leads to solving Part (ii) in some efficient way.

What I've done is to work out the characteristic polynomial of $\mathbf A$ and solve it to find the other eigenvalues ($9$ again and $-9$), and I saved a little time by dividing through by $(\lambda - 9)$ in that process.

But I don't see how to use Part (i) to efficiently find orthogonal eigenvectors and I feel I'm probably missing a trick.

Comment: I didn't find $9$ as a double eigenvalue.

Comment: @Bernard I believe that part is correct; for example an online eigenvalues calculator gives the same: https://www.symbolab.com/solver/matrix-eigenvalues-calculator/eigenvalues%20%5Cbegin%7Bpmatrix%7D7%264%26-4%5C%5C%204%261%268%5C%5C%20-4%268%261%5Cend%7Bpmatrix%7D

Comment: You're right, I had a sign error on computing the characteristic polynomial by hand. Sorry!

Comment: @Bernard Having worked through the rest of the exercise by hand this morning I can fully sympathise!

Answer (score 1):

If $x$ is an eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda$ then we have,

$(A- \lambda I )x = O$

Now for $\lambda = -9$

$$\begin{pmatrix}16&4&-4\\4 & 10&8 \\-4 &8&10\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix} 
$$

$$
(R_1\to R_1-4R_2, R_3\to R_3 +R_2)$$

$$\begin{pmatrix}0&-36&-36\\4 &10  &8 \\0 &18&18\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix} $$

$$\implies b+c = 0 \text{ and } 2a+5b+4c=0$$

Now $r$ is orthogonal to $x$

$$\implies rx^T = 0 \implies -2a +c = 0 \implies c = 2a$$

Let $a = 1 \implies c = 2 \text{ and } b = -c = -2$

So,

> $$x = \begin{pmatrix}1 \\-2\\2\end{pmatrix}$$

Also $A$ is symmetrical. So automatically the eigenvectors are orthogonal. Let $$y = \begin{pmatrix}u\\v\\w\end{pmatrix}$$ be the 3rd eigen vector.

$$ry^T = 0 \implies-2u+w = 0\implies w = 2u$$

$$xy^T = 0\implies u-2v+2w = 0 \implies 5u+2v = 0 \implies v = -5/2u$$

Let $$u = 2\implies v = 5\text{ and } w = 4$$

So,

> $$ y = \begin{pmatrix}2\\5\\4\end{pmatrix}$$

And $\det(A) = 9\times9\times-9 = -729$

Comment: Thank you for this. Is there any way to short-cut having to find the characteristic polynomial and its roots in this question? Finding the third eigenvector using the fact that it is perpendicular to the other two saves some time but the way the question is structured still leaves me feeling like there is a trick I've missed.